# Almacenar en variable ID AI

Tags: php, mysql

Buen dia,

Tengo dos tablas A y B. En A almaceno el registro de las facturas como: idFactura, idVendedor, idCliente, numFactura,Fecha etc y en la otra almaceno datos como idVenta, numFactura, codProducto, cantProducto, etc.

Entonces en una posible busqueda lo correcto seria relacionarlas por numFactura pero quisiera saber si hay alguna manera de que en la tabla B agregar el la columna idFactura y por relacionarlas por idFactura que se genera solo y tiene el atributo AI.

Espero se pueda, agradecere sus respuestas.

Comment: Añádes las etiquetas php y mysql pero tu pregunta no incluye código que estés intentando usar, consultas que estés probando, las sentencias DML (los `create table` para saber el tipo de dato de las columnas). La mejor forma de contarnos lo que nos intentas contar es mostrando estos detalles. Puedes editar tu pregunta usando el enlace editar que está justo debajo de las etiquetas :)

Comment: Después de insertar la factura obtén su id con [lastInsertId](https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdo.lastinsertid.php) si estás usando _PDO_ o [insert_id](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.insert-id.php) si usas _mysqli_ para acceso a base de datos.

Comment: Triby casualmente estaba por publicar la solucion que estuve buscando por otro lado y es la misma que me das $lastInsertId = mysqli_insert_id($con);. Gracias